# Проблема в VS C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Прошу не кидаться тапками. Что VS Code от меня хочет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых хочет, чтобы вы не использовали ```new()```, а использовали ```new Dictionary<int, string>()``` из-за того, что недоступно в более старой версии (которая у вас как раз). А во-вторых, чтобы использовать некоторый функционал необходимо подключить пространство имен (в вашем случае нужно написать вверху ```using System.Collections.Generic;```). Чтобы так постоянно не писать можете воспользоваться "лампочкой", нажмите пкм по коду (который горит красным) -> "Быстрые действия или рефакторинг" -> ```using System.Collections.Generic;```

Comment: Открыть "быстрые действия или рефакторинг" можно так же, если нажать сочетание клавиш "ctrl+ ю"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Подключите пространство имён System.Collections.Generic (напишите в самом вверху команду `using System.Collections.Generic;`)
2. У Вас в коде используется оператор `new()`, а в данном случае надо использовать `new Dictionary<int, string>()`.

Comment: Для второго пункта можно еще просто пересоздать проект для .NET 5 и перенести в него код.

Comment: Да, так тоже можно

Comment: @aepot На данный момент актуально уже на .NET 6 переходить, к тому же он LTS

Comment: @ГеннадийП для этого надо как минимум 2022 студию накатить, но пока лень.